Css while using position absolute, relative to a item makes both of the items disappear
I was trying to make a search input below the navbar but when I use position absolute, relative to my icon both icon and search input disapear. But if I dont put it to relative it appears. I want my search input to appear outside that green area.
I even tried to make some upper div relative, but then search input scrolls into the green area.
I thought position absolute makes element to go out of the flow. So why in inspector it exists but I cant see it. I need the search input outside the green area.
(Sorry for not being able to give icons. You can put any image in the img tag to see the problem)


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}


/* Google-fonts icon style (can be changed) */

.material-symbols-rounded {
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 0, "wght" 400, "GRAD" 0, "opsz" 20;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings: "FILL" 0, "wght" 350, "GRAD" 0, "opsz" 20;
}


/* Actual styling starts here */


/* Navbar styling starts */

.header {
  background-color: #128d50;
  height: 3.0625rem;
}

.nav-container {
  padding: 0 11.71875%;
  height: 3.0625rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.nav-container a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.875rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-div img {
  width: 1.5625rem;
}

.nav-div .search-toggle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* search animation */

.nav-div .search,
.nav-div .close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.search-toggle .close {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.search-toggle.active-search .close {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.search-toggle.active-search .search {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* This is the code giving me the problem */

.search-box {
  position: relative;
}

.search-box .search-field {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.search-field input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-field img {
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
}
<header class="header">
  <!-- Navbar's code -->
  <nav class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav-div">
      <a class="nav-li" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <a class="nav-li" href="#">Library</a>
      <a class="nav-li" href="#">navigation</a>
      <a class="nav-li" href="#"> Links</a>
      <a class="nav-li" href="#">Archive</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-div">
      <a href="#">new</a>
      <div class="search-box">
        <div class="search-toggle">
          <img class="search" src="./svg/search.svg" alt="">
          <img class="close" src="./svg/close.svg" alt="">
          <div class="search-field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <img src="./svg/search2.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <p>Login</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>



I just can't make search-box position relative with search-field position absolute. I need the search input outside the green area.

"So why in inspector it exists but I cant see it." - because you applied overflow-x: hidden; to all elements, which implicitly makes overflow-y take the value auto, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1427878
